# select column magento

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering how you can select columns. Above you can see the sql I wanna write in the controller. But I want to do this the wright way. Like other sql statements in magento.

I tried to add ->columns('o.sku AS  SKU') but this didn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
//sql
$readresult="SELECT o.name AS  'Product', o.sku AS  'SKU', c.entity_id AS  'Order', c.customer_email AS  'Email', c.customer_firstname AS  'Voornaam', c.customer_lastname AS  'Achternaam', c.customer_middlename AS  'Tussenvoegsel', o.product_options AS 'Options', a.telephone AS  'Telefoon', a.postcode AS  'Postcode', a.street AS  'Street', a.city AS  'City', c.increment_id AS 'Bestelnr' FROM magento_sales_flat_order AS c INNER JOIN magento_sales_flat_order_item AS o ON c.entity_id = o.order_id INNER JOIN magento_sales_flat_order_address AS a ON a.parent_id = c.entity_id WHERE o.product_id =".$product." GROUP BY c.entity_id ORDER BY o.sku;";


//THE MAGENTO WAY!
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$o = $resource->getTableName('magento_sales_flat_order');
$o_item = $resource->getTableName('magento_sales_flat_order_item');
$o_address = $resource->getTableName('magento_sales_flat_order_address');
$select = $read->select()->from(array('c'=>$o))
    ->join(array('o'=>$o_item), 'c.entity_id = o.order_id', array(o.sku AS  'SKU'))
    ->join(array('a'=>$o_address), 'a.parent_id = c.entity_id', array())
    ->where('o.product_id', $product)
    ->group('c.entity_id')
    ->order('o.sku');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You souldn't work like this with core modules at all. Those low level SQL queries should be used by resource models *only*. Especially not within a controller.

You should get an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` by calling `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()` and build your query from there. Just have a look at the source code to find out about how to do that exactly; start at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php and work your way down the inheritance chain.

For example, you can add a `WHERE` using something like `$collection->addAttributeToSearchFilter()`.

Magento's got great database abstraction and you sould definately be using it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not adjusting core modules, I'm developing a custom module.
I solved the problem and now it works like I want it to work. But I'm afraid, like you said, that I'm doing it the wrong way. Any good resources that I can look at to see how it needs to be done?

Comment: Almost each and every resource on Magento on the web is either absolutely wrong/outdated or way too hard to follow if you don't know Magento basics. The only really good one I found was [this recording of a week long class on Mage Dev Fundamentals](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/descriptions#fundamentals-of-magento-development).

Comment: Also, I didn't say you were editing core modules. I was trying to say that you should use Magento's core functionalities on a very high level - models or resource models. No deeper than that. :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll look into the class you found. Thanks for the help and advice! And indeed not that easy to develop (I'm only into magento now for like 3 days, so all very new for me)

Comment: I get your pain. :) But after you've watched this class, you will not only understand Magento, I bet you'll even like the framework so much that you want to write even non-webshops in it. Have fun and tell me if I was right afterwards! :)